# PHP / AJAX: Retrieve value from submit button, and store in a $_SESSION variable?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I currently have a Blog page, which displays blog posts dynamically, using .getJSON and .append. For each post in the blog, I have appended a 'Read More' button, which will direct to another URL with more information regarding the post.

I have dynamically appended the 'Read More' button using:

```js
`$('#content').append('<form class="blogReadMore" method="post" action="blogReadMore.php"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" name="readMoreButton" value="' + entry.id + '">Read More</button></form>');`.
```

When the submit button is pressed, I've used AJAX.on('submit'), but creating a

```
$_SESSION variable in php does not seem to work:
```

`$_SESSION['read_more_blog_post_id'] = $_POST['readMoreButton'];`.

If I change the php assignment line to `$_SESSION['read_more_blog_post_id'] = "69";` then I can access this value - otherwise I get null.

Any help greatly appreaciated

Comment: Are you getting errors? Is the ajax going thru? Is the session not saved? Your question provides very little information for actual debugging the issue itself.

Comment: I am not getting any errors, but when trying to access the $_SESSION['read_more_blog_post_id'] I get a null value

Comment: Please edit your post too and add any additional information to it. It seems that your value is not saved.

Comment: If I change the assignment line to `$_SESSION['read_more_blog_post_id'] = "69";`, then this works, and I can access the value.

Comment: Then `$_POST['readMoreButton'];` is `null`. It seems that you need to learn how to debug.

Comment: Is it possible to access the value from a button using $_POST?

Comment: You can use a `hidden` field to sent the value. Basically move the `value` from your submit button to a `hidden` field. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden).

Comment: This approach seems like a good suggestion, thanks

Comment: When using AJAX to submit the form, what should I include for `data:`

Comment: You lost me. `data:`?

Comment: Currently, in my AJAX, I have: `data: $('.blogReadMore').serialize()`

Comment: It's fine the way it is. It will serialize the whole form. Including the new hidden field.

Comment: In that case, the hidden field hasn't solved my problem. I still get a `null` value

Comment: Since we've come this far. [Join me in the chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160616/lewisw44-q)

Comment: I only have 15 reputation

Comment: So you can't join the chat room? Jesus, who came up with this system...

Comment: Ok. Do a `var_dump` of your session once the ajax is started. We can start from there.

Comment: Okay, I have it working slightly better, I think there are other areas which need improvement

Comment: I have the `session` variable set from `post`, but it is just the wrong value (it is set to the id of the last post, not the one I clicked)

Comment: Well, that's an entirely different issue then.

Comment: Thanks for the help getting me this far :)

Comment: Where is you ajax code that you are using to post to your php? Also, if you are appending multiple `<form class="blogReadMore"..` than `data: $('.blogReadMore').serialize()` will not work as you are not specifying which `.blogReadMore` value that you clicked on, but all the `.blogReadMore` values.

Comment: The AJAX code is within the $.getJSON construct, but outside of the $.each loop